# Data type conversion via sql query

Tags: python, django, oracle

I have problem with data type conversion. 
Using django and pypyodbc lib I'm trying to recieive data from oracle DB (external) and save it into local app DB.

```
import pypyodbc
def get_data(request):
    conn = pypyodbc.connect("DSN=...")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT value FROM table")
    data = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in data:
       d = External_Data(first_val = row[0])
       d.save()
```

The output from value is "0,2" and I've received error message:

```
could not convert string to float: b',02'
```

When I changed sql statement to:

```
SELECT cast(value as numeric(10,2) from table)
```

I received error message:

```
[<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
```

How to change that data to get float data and save it. I use DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2) as model field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this problem comes with implicit type change.

when you get data from your `get_data` function, `row[0]` var in `for` loop is seemed like `Bytes` variable.

So First of all, I recommend to check `row[0]`'s data type with `print(type(row[0]))`.

If result is `Bytes`, you can do like this:

```
import pypyodbc
def get_data(request):
    conn = pypyodbc.connect("DSN=...")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT value FROM table")
    data = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in data:
       data = float(str(row[0]).replace(',','.'))
       d = External_Data(first_val=data)
       d.save()
```

Comment: The problem was about comma separator. I got "0,2" insted of "0.2" and python iterpretate it as string. I decided to change sql statement using replace(value, ' , ' , ' . ') . Now it works for me. Thx